# Import a notebook into another book in Azure Synapse

Tags: python-3.x, azure-synapse

I have one notebook1 in synapse ws with python code that contains some variable.
I have created another notebook2 and I'd like to use the variables from notebook1. I tried to import as a package, but it didn't work.
Has any one done that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the variables from another Notebook by referencing using `%run` in present Notebook.

**Example:**

This is my **Notebook2** in which I have defined two variables.

[image]

Then In **Notebook1** reference the `Notebook2` like below `%run Notebook2`.

When you execute it, you can access the variables from it.

[image]

***Note:*** Make sure you publish the **Calling Notebook(Notebook2)** to access the recent changes in that Notebook.

and don't execute any code in `%run` cell otherwise it will error like below.

[image]